# Camel unit of work

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to understand the unit of work concept in Camel.  I have a simple question hopefully someone here can help.

If there are multiple routes involved in routing the Excachange for example

```
from("aws-sqs:Q1").to("direct:processMe");//route1

from("direct:processMe").to("direct:aws-post");//route2

from("direct:aws-post").to("htt4:myservice");//route3
```

Is the unit of work invoked at the end of each routes? Or only at the end of route3?  In my example, will the SQS message be deleted off of SQS once route1 completes?  Or will it wait until my message reaches "myservice"?

Thanks.

FOLLOW UP:

I've modified the route slighty:

```
from("aws-sqs:Q1").to("direct:processMe");//route1

from("direct:processMe").process(
   new Processor(){
       public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          throw new RuntimeException("fail on purpose");
       }
   }
).to("direct:aws-post");//route2

from("direct:aws-post").to("http4:myservice");//route3
```

The thought process is this:
If the unit of work is invoked at end of each route then once the message is read from SQS Queue it will be acknowledged as read by the SQS component.  On the other hand if unit of work is only invoked once the Exchange is done routing through all routes, then the exception in route 2 will result in the message not being acknowledged and will be available for redelivery once the visibility period expires.

The test showed that the message remains on the Q despite being read by first route.  It is picked up again and again (until it ends up in dead letter q).  As such I strongly believe that the unit boundary is defined by the end of Exchange being routed.

Answer (score 2):

A [unit of work](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/UnitOfWork.html) is basically a transaction.

By default a message for a route (a camel `Exchange`) runs inside a single `UnitOfWork` context.

In your example there are 3 `UnitOfWork`s set up, starting at each `from` and finishing at the final `to` in each route.

I would expect the message from SQS to be consumed after the 1st route finishes. To test, you could add in a sleep to allow you to check the queue.

```
from("direct:processMe").process(new Processor() 
        { void process() {  try  { Thread.sleep(60000L) } catch (Exception e) { } } 
    }).to("direct:aws-post")
```

If you want the message to remain on the queue until `myservice` gets the message then you need to put the processing in a single route.

Comment: I'll give your idea a try.  But I am doubtful.  In the Camel book it states "When the exchange is done, either the onComplete or onFailure method is invoked,
depending on whether the exchange failed."  Since the unit of work is associated with Exchange I would expect it to be executed only once exchange is done routing.  I'll give your idea a try next week.  I'll post here with the results.

Comment: That correct. The scope of the exchange is the `from()` to the `.to()`. I dont think you can propgate a UnitOfWork across multiple routes, but I might be wrong.

Comment: See my edit.   Also I found this in the book, look at last sentence:

How UnitOfWork is orchestrated: Camel will automatically inject a new UnitOfWork into an Exchange when it’s routed.  This is done by an internal processor, UnitOfWorkProcessor, which is involved in the start of every route. When the Exchange is done, this processor invokes the registered
Synchronization callbacks. The UnitOfWork boundaries are always at the beginning and end of the Exchange being routed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a great explanation as to the unit of work boundary:

> "The OnCompletion DSL name is used to define an action that is to take place when a Unit of Work is completed.
>
> A Unit of Work is a Camel concept that encompasses an entire exchange. See Section 43.1, “Exchanges”. The onCompletion command has the following features:
>
> - The scope of the OnCompletion command can be global or per route. A route scope overrides global scope.
>     OnCompletion can be configured to be triggered on success for failure.
> - The onWhen predicate can be used to only trigger the onCompletion in certain situations.
>     You can define whether or not to use a thread pool, though the default is no thread pool."

In case of SQS processing, the consumer defines `onCompletion` on the exchange. So it is invoked only after the exchange is done routing.

The whole answer can be found here: [Apache Camel Development Guide2.11. OnCompletion](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/oncompletion)