# Does shareUnitOfWork have negative input on performance in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I had dead letter queue but the message was changed due to multicast, so I learned that shareUnitOfWork should be used. I checked and it did what I needed.

What performance input would it have? Is there any other effect of sharing unit of work?

I think understanding the concept of unit of work would help. I found those: [Camel unit of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371202/camel-unit-of-work) but still it doesn't 'click'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it has a performance effect, because when you use `shareUnitOfWork` **it only makes a copy of an existing instead of a new UnitOfWork**.

Every [Camel Exchange](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/Exchange.java) (wrapper around a message routed by Camel) has **exactly 1 [UnitOfWork](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/UnitOfWork.java) that is injected by Camel when a message routing starts**.

So normally, this happens when a new message arrives at a route consumer.

```
from("file:myDirectory?delete=true...")...
```

Whenever a new file is read by this route, Camel creates an Exchange that contains the message with the file content and headers and it also **injects a new, empty UnitOfWork** into the Exchange.

This **UnitOfWork contains various useful stuff for when the Exchange routing is done** (have a look at the [Interface](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/UnitOfWork.java)).

For example the file consumer above should delete the processed files after routing them. To accomplish this, the consumer adds a tasks to the UnitOfWork. When the routing of the Exchange is done, this task is executed.

Now, for EIPs that **multiply a single message into multiple** (e.g. [Splitter](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html), [Multicast](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/multicast-eip.html)), by default, **every newly created "child" Exchange gets an new, empty UnitOfWork**. Just as every other Exchange.

This brings up the problem that the **information of the source Exchange's UnitOfWork is no more present** on the "children's" UnitOfWork. In your case, the original message is not the original message of the source Exchange, but the newly created message.

To **propagate the UnitOfWork of the source Exchange to all newly created "child" Exchanges**, you set the `shareUnitOfWork` statement.

When it is set, Camel does not inject a **new** UnitOfWork into the child Exchanges, but a **copy** of the source Exchange's UnitOfWork.

When you want to learn about such Camel concepts, I highly recommend the book [Camel in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition).

Comment: Thank you! Camel in action is in my book list already ;)